# How to get groups of vector indices corresponding to the same value?

Tags: r

Given some arbitrary vector `v`, I want to produce a list `index.vectors`, consisting of vectors of indices in `v` for each of the values represented in `v`<sup>1</sup>.

For example, if `v` is the vector

```
v <- c(4, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1)
```

...then the desired list `index.vectors` would be:

```
> index.vectors
$`4`
[1] 1 5

$`0`
[1] 2 6

$`1`
[1]  3  4  7  9 10

$`2`
[1] 8
```

Is there a built-in/standard way to produce this sort of grouping from a vector of values?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Whenever possible, `names(index.vectors)` should be the vector of unique values in `v`, in their order of first appearance.  For the sake of this question, feel free to assume that the values in `v` can be coerced into suitable names for list slots.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would simply use

```
split(seq_along(v), v)
```

However, if you really want the result to be in the order you want, use

```
split(seq_along(v), factor(v, levels = unique(v)))
```